# Cannot find module 'socket.io' in Visual Studio node.js project on typesctipt

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio, typescript, socket.io

I have some node.js project on Visual Studio, It works fine,
But when i try to import  'socket.io' it shows error - Cannot find module 'socket.io'. I cannot even build project.  it is installed in node_modules folder, but anyway  not found.
Any Ideas?

code:

```
import express = require('express');
import http = require('http');
import path = require('path');
import io = require('socket.io');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I had forgotten to add typings for socket.io